# Wrap URL as filesystem path

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to call [a python function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) that takes an absolute path as an argument, but the file I want to reference is on the web.

Without cloning the file locally, is there a way I can refer to the file that will make python *think* the file is local?

In other words, I want to wrap the URL in a variable `my_file_path`, and have this return `True`:

```
os.path.isfile(my_file_path)
```

Note that I need to fake a file system path, as other calls in the program I am using are expecting a path, and not a file-like object (this includes other functions that call [the function I linked](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html))

Answer (score 2):

A really great way to do this is with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) library. You can get a file-like object using the [`stream=True`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) option to the `get` function:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events', stream=True)
loadmat(r.raw, ...)
```

In the case of needing an actual path, you can use the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module as well:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fd:
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events', stream=True)

    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
        fd.write(chunk)
    fd.flush()

    loadmat(fd.name)

# other code here, where the temp file no longer exists but the data has been read
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make Python take a URL where it wants a path.

In many cases—like the very function you linked in your question—it actually wants a file-like object, and the object returned by, e.g., `urlopen` is file-like. But in other cases, that doesn't work.

So, what can you do?

1. Below the Python level, your operating system may have a way to mount different kinds of remote paths as if they were part of your local filesystem.
2. At a higher level, write your own wrapper that just downloads the file to a temporary file. That temporary file will, of course, pass the `os.path.isfile(my_file_path)` test that you wanted, and will work with everything else that needs a file. But it means that you need to keep the two "layers" of your code—the part that wants to deal with URLs, and the part that needs to deal with functions that can only take local files—separate, and write the interface between those layers. On at least some platforms, you can create a temporary file that never gets flushed to disk unless necessary. (You can even create a temporary file that doesn't appear anywhere in the directory tree, but that wouldn't help here, because then you obviously can't pass a pathname around…) So you're not "cloning the file" in any sense that actually matters.